# jquery youtube api - when a video stops playing i want it to disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

This is my jquery code:

```
/* videoplayer controls */
$('#sjvslider li a').bind('click', function() {
$('#sjvslider li a').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active'); // sets the thumbnail that what just clicked.
var vidNum = $(this).attr('rel');
var myVid = $("#video"+vidNum+"").html();
$('.videoplayer').html(myVid);
});
```

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="videoDiv" class="videoplayer"></div>

<div id="video1" >
<object width="508" height="273" id="myytplayer" data="http://www.youtube.com/v/CezWPkoWXbY?version=3&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0&amp;enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer">
 <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
 <param name="bgcolor" value="#000">
 </object>
 </div>
 <div id="video2" class="novideo">
 <object width="508" height="273" id="myytplayer" data="http://www.youtube.com/v/qhluM6nrCVs?version=3&amp;enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer">
 <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
 <param name="bgcolor" value="#000">
 </object>
 </div>
```

And then i have some links with some textlinks to get the right videoID.

```
<ul id="sjvslider">
<li><a href="#" rel="1">VIDEO 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" rel="2">VIDEO 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Ultimately what I want to do is after the user clicks one of these links and plays the video, when the video stops playing i want it to disappear because I have a background image underneath the videos that i want to show again.

Is there some way to do this with jquery, perhaps accessing the youtube api?

Answer (score 3):

Yup, you want to add an event listener using the API's `player.addEventListener()` method and listen for the onStateChange event. It broadcasts a number (0 for stopped, 2 for paused, etc.) based on the player's state (playing, paused, ended, etc.). When that event is triggered by the "stop" state, you can fire a jQuery function to `.hide()` or `.remove()` or whatever your movie container.

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html#Events (the player.addEventListner() documentation is right *above* this anchor on that page, FYI. Easy to miss otherwise).

EDIT: note that you'll need to enable the YouTube API for the embedded video as described [here](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html#GettingStarted).

Comment: yep, I added that. I guess I was just a little confused how to add the event listener using jquery syntax.  I'll look at your links and see if i can get it to work.

Comment: So i have taken a 2nd path, i have one page using just javascript + youtube api. I can get one video to load into the player by passing a videoID to a function that contains all of the fun stuff from swfObject. When i click my first link, the video loads and i am getting some feedback from the youtube api. great! But when i click on the 2nd link to load the next video, nothing happens.  I want to write just once function that will load the swf into place and when it reaches its end, it goes away.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I started using a jquery plugin called jQuery.tubeplayer.js.  It has a parameter called "onPlayerEnded" -- so in that I have a function that removes the div container that is holding the youtube video.  so that works great except now when i click the next thumb in the playlist, it can't find the ID to load the movie into. Perhaps i need to remove and then add it back, empty? Any thoughts?

Comment: i think i have solved my problem. the plugin was extremely helpful.